# Cannot access variables in a Swift class from Objective-C file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode6

I'm trying to continue with Swift in an existing project I had started in Objective-C.  I followed the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) and I managed to access a Swift class from an Objective-C file, via including the *"ProductModuleName-Swift.h"* header in my Obj-C file.

At this point here's my code:

```
#include "Pianoconcert_App-Swift.h"

@interface ModelsVC ()

@end

@implementation ModelsVC
// And all that kind of stuff
// ...
-(IBAction)comanda:(UIButton *)sender {
    ComandaTableVC *controller = (ComandaTableVC *)self.tabBarController.viewControllers[2];
    // Here goes the problematic code
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
}
```

This piece of code has no problems.  But now I just want to set one of the variables in the Swift class like this: `controller.selectedModel = sender.tag`, but Xcode just tells me the variable does not exist.

Here's an extract of my Swift class:

```
import UIKit

class ComandaTableVC: UITableViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    // Declaration of some constants and variables
    // And here goes the one
    var selectedModel: Int = 0
    // And a bunch more of variables and functions
    // ...
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  The class seems fully included and, actually, I can access that variable and all the others if I use the class from **another Swift file**, like this:

```
var controller: ComandaTableVC = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[2] as ComandaTableVC
controller.selectedModel = 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been resolved finally, but I can't explain how.
Suddenly the compiler threw a build error telling me that the file *Pianoconcert_App-Swift.h* could not be found.

I changed it for *PianoconcertApp-Swift.h*, deleting the **underscore that replaced the blank space**, and now I can access all the variables and constants correctly.